# starting HBase error and table creation fail

Tags: hbase

I am trying to follow along the [hbase quickstart](http://hbase.apache.org/book/quickstart.html), but I'm running into an error I can't seem to resolve. I'm using the hbase-0.98.7-hadoop2 distribution. When I start hbase with `bin/start-hbase.sh`, I see in the logs:

```
2014-11-08 01:40:07,911 INFO  [main] util.VersionInfo: HBase 0.98.7-hadoop2
2014-11-08 01:40:07,911 INFO  [main] util.VersionInfo: Subversion git://acer/usr/src/hbase -r 800c23e2207aa3f9bddb7e9514d8340bcfb89277
2014-11-08 01:40:07,912 INFO  [main] util.VersionInfo: Compiled by apurtell on Wed Oct  8 15:58:11 PDT 2014
2014-11-08 01:40:08,195 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-1569965, built on 02/20/2014 09:09 GMT
2014-11-08 01:40:08,196 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:host.name=vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64
2014-11-08 01:40:08,196 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:java.version=1.7.0_72
2014-11-08 01:40:08,196 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
2014-11-08 01:40:08,196 INFO  [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: Server environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_72/jre
```

[...]

> 2014-11-08 01:40:18,471 ERROR
>   [RS_OPEN_REGION-vagrant-ubuntu-precise-64:22299-0]
>   handler.OpenRegionHandler: Failed open of
>   region=hbase:namespace,,1415321583827.49f3bd83d8a3431fe3cd69e565920703.,
>   starting to roll back the global memstore size.
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not instantiate a region
>   instance.
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.newHRegion(HRegion.java:4261)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.openHRegion(HRegion.java:4569)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.openHRegion(HRegion.java:4542)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.openHRegion(HRegion.java:4498)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.openHRegion(HRegion.java:4449)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.handler.OpenRegionHandler.openRegion(OpenRegionHandler.java:482)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.handler.OpenRegionHandler.process(OpenRegionHandler.java:145)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.executor.EventHandler.run(EventHandler.java:128)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.newHRegion(HRegion.java:4258)
>           ... 10 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Need table descriptor
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.(HRegion.java:555)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.(HRegion.java:531)
>           ... 15 more

Now, when I open an HBase shell to create a table as in the quickstart, I get

```
$ bin/hbase shell
2014-11-08 01:47:18,918 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 0.98.7-hadoop2, r800c23e2207aa3f9bddb7e9514d8340bcfb89277, Wed Oct  8 15:58:11 PDT 2014

hbase(main):001:0> create 'test', 'cf'
2014-11-08 01:48:44,064 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

ERROR: java.io.IOException: Table Namespace Manager not ready yet, try again later
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.getNamespaceDescriptor(HMaster.java:3172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.createTable(HMaster.java:1727)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.createTable(HMaster.java:1766)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$2.callBlockingMethod(MasterProtos.java:40470)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2027)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FifoRpcScheduler$1.run(FifoRpcScheduler.java:74)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

JPS reports that I have an HMaster running:

```
$ jps
1391 HMaster
1955 Jps
```

I even have this in `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 ubuntu.ubuntu-domain ubuntu
```

Help? I thought the package is supposed to be self-contained. It shouldn't depend on a running version of zookeeper, right?

Any help would be appreciated. I'm on Ubuntu 64-bit using Oracle Java 1.7.0_72.

I found someone else's solution was to run HBase 0.94, but that can't be the best solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on standalone mode , then paste this script in hbase-site.xml. Make a directory HBASE and change in script according to your system.

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>/home/user17/HBASE/hbase</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/home/user17/HBASE/zookeeper</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2181</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.master</name> 
        <value>hadoop-master:60000</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

then set java path in hbase-env.sh

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/user17/jdk/
```

then give the hbase path in .bashrc

```
export HBASE_INSTALL=/home/user17/BigData/hbase-0.94.8
export PATH=$PATH:$HBASE_INSTALL/bin
```

then go to bin directory of hbase and run command

```
./start-all.sh

 hbase shell
```

let me know if not work

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. Same error as I posted in my equestion. I might have to use an older version of hbase: 0.94 instead of trying 0.96 or 0.98 :(

Comment: you have right version. download zookeeper then go to zookeeper/conf and update Directory=/home/user/zookeeper(according to your system) then go to zookeerper/bin and execute command ./zkServer.sh start and check 2181 port  is working or not by command netstat -nl|grep 2181

Comment: Same problem here with HBase 1.1.2 
Stuck on Region in Transition FAILED_OPEN for hbase:namespace with a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Need table descriptor   exception on the RegionServer. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

You have this problem because you forget input all of your "Master name and slave name" in your "/.../hbase/conf/regionservers" example : (vim /opt/hbase/conf/regionservers)
`Master <---this
slave1
slave2
slave3
.
.
.`

Comment: Thx for the note. I've moved on from HBase since my post, but I'll try to verify this when I get some time to reboot HBase in my project..

Answer (score -1):

First start zookeeper than change `hbase-env.sh` as below.

```
# Tell HBase whether it should manage its own instance of Zookeeper or not.
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false
```